# Doubt about an exercise of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the excerpt from the textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling.

[image]

Here, $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ and "increasing" means relation to inclusion. i.e. $X\subseteq Y\implies f(X)\subseteq f(Y)$. $s(n)$ is the successor function. i.e. $s(n)=n+1$.

From $H=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}H_{n}=H_{0}\cup (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n})=\varnothing\cup(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n})=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$.

In short, $H=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$.

$S(H)=S(\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}H_{n})=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}S(H_{n})=S(H_{0})\cup S(H_{1})\cup S(H_{2})\cup S(H_{3})...=H_{1} \cup H_{2} \cup H_{3} \cup H_{4} ... =\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$.

In short, $S(H)=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$.

To sum up, we have $H=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$ and $S(H)=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}$. This implies $H = S(H)$.

If my reasoning is correct. Question (d) will be wrong.

Please have a check!

Comment: Just to clarify: Is $P(A)$ the power set of $A$? And does "increasing" mean in relation to inclusion? I.e. $X\subseteq Y\implies S(X)\subseteq f(Y)$?

Comment: Also, what is $s$? There is a reference in the question to the number "$s(n)$, but that is not defined anywhere...

Comment: @5xum I suspect $s(n)=n+1$.

Comment: You are assuming that $S$ is continuous. Why is it continuous?

Comment: @5xum, Yes, $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ and "increasing" means relation to inclusion. i.e. $X\subseteq Y\implies f(X)\subseteq f(Y)$. $s(n)$ is the successor function. i.e. $s(n)=n+1$. I just add to my post for clarity, Many thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you mean  
statement $S(\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}H_{n})=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}S(H_{n})$ is problematic. I read it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Consequences.

Comment: You are confusing two things. There this is *the image* and here it is *the value*. This confusion is not rare when first dealing with functions from sets to sets. But you need to be careful and notice that difference. Consider $A$ to be a sufficiently large set, and $S(X)$ to be the power set of $X$. Now start with $\varnothing$, then $H_n$ are all finite, so $\bigcup S(H_n)$ is a countably infinite set. But its power set is much larger.

Comment: Some possibly helpful examples: Let $A$ be a well-ordered set, *e.g.*, some ordinal number. If $H$ is a proper subset of $A$ define $S(H)=H\cup\{a\}$ where $a$ is the least element of $A\setminus H;$ and define $S(A)=A.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is that you confuse evaluation with image.

Recall that if $F\colon X\to Y$ is a function, we *often* write $F(A)=\{F(a)\mid a\in A\}$ as a subset of $Y$. But if your function is from sets to sets, then $F(A)$ is an element of $Y$, and not [necessarily] a subset of $Y$.

This is one of the reasons that in set theory you would see $F[A]$ or $F"A$ used to denote $\{F(a)\mid a\in A\}$.

In turn this implies that you are mistaken about the continuity of $S$ here. There is no reason for $S(\bigcup H_n)$ to be equal to $\bigcup S(H_n)$. As [bof suggests in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647167/doubt-about-an-exercise-of-set-theory#comment5467493_2647167), take $A$ to be a well-ordered set which is large enough (e.g. $\{\frac{n}{n+1}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{1\}$) and $S(H)=H\cup\{a\}$ for $a$ as the least element not in $H$; and $S(A)=A$.

Then $H_0=\varnothing$, and $H_{n+1}=S(H_n)$ will give you finite initial segments of the order. So $\bigcup H_n$ will be just $\{\frac n{n+1}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\neq A$, but $S(\bigcup H_n)=A$ itself.

Comment: I'm clear. Many thanks ^_^

Comment: Hi @Asaf Karagila, I have posted a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687252/axiom-of-dependent-choice-implies-axiom-of-countable-choice but not received any answer. Could you please have a look at it? I wonder why I still haven't got any answer although my question is clear and I made effort to deal with it?

Comment: You received a comment indicating that it's okay. There's really not much more to add. This is why often times the suggestion is to post your formalization as an answer to your original question rather than a separate question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Asaf Karagila!